# Reducing the size of UISwitch in Xamarin Forms does not work

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, uiswitch

In Xamarin Forms, I created a custom renderer for `Switch`. On iOS, I updated the scale transform to make it smaller than its default size:

```
Control.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale((float)0.75, (float)0.75);
```

While this successfully resizes the `Switch`, it doesn't resize its bounding box. How can I resize it as well?

[image]

Here the background color of the `Switch` is set to red in XAML. It looks like the original bounds are still being maintained even though the thumb is smaller.

Comment: Umm maybe try using the height and width request properties if possible!

Comment: Those do not work. `UISwitch` is not meant to be resizable. That's why you will find examples using a scale transform.

Comment: Is that so? Never really used it before so i do not know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Scale` property of Switch in Xamarin.Forms:

```
   <Switch OnColor="Orange" Scale="0.75" BackgroundColor="Red"
    ThumbColor="Green" />
```