# Xamarin Forms: Html label is showing blank content in ios

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, label

I am using `Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel` for showing data on my project. It is working fine on android and windows. But nothing is showing in ios devices.

My code:

```
<htmllabel:HtmlLabel
    x:Name="message_label"
    VerticalOptions="Start"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    TextColor="Black">
    <htmllabel:HtmlLabel.FontSize>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnIdiom.Phone>20</OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnIdiom.Desktop>20</OnIdiom.Desktop>
        </OnIdiom>
    </htmllabel:HtmlLabel.FontSize>
</htmllabel:HtmlLabel>


message_label.Text = "htmldata";
```

I have uploaded a sample [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJeGUKtlN46bApI_DVezkhwZx9v5-7Kt/view?usp=sharing) for the reference.

Comment: Which effect did you want to achieve ? In your sample tag <p> will have no obvious effect on text . You could set `<u>`(underline)  or some other tag like `"<span style='color: green'>xxx</span>"` . Your sample works fine on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't want any effect, I need to show only the data. Is the data visible in ios for you? Could you please provide the working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , you seems forget to init the renderer in specific platforms .

#### in iOS

```
using LabelHtml.Forms.Plugin.iOS;
```

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
   HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
   LoadApplication(new App());

   return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

I used the tag `<u>` to add under line of the label .

[image]

You could check the demo from https://github.com/luczha/HtmlLabel_demo .

Comment: Downloaded the sample and run on a simulator, a blank page is showing again.

Comment: What is the ios version of your simulator ?

Comment: I means the version of iOS , 13.x , 12.x ?

Comment: Also I don't need underline in the data

Comment: Try to test it on 13.x , and set <u> </u> to <p></p> .

Comment: All my simulators are 11.3.1, how can I upgrade it to 13.x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215998/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Comment: Does my answer work ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221344/reducing-the-size-of-uiswitch-in-xamarin-forms-does-not-work/60222923#60222923